# Is the dihedral group admissible?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

I want to ask:

When is the dihedral group $D_n$ admissible? Or, when does the Latin square of the Cayley table of a dihedral group have a transversal?

thanks

Comment: You should at least provide a reference where the specific meaning of the word 'admissible' you have in mind is explained: it has way too may meanings! Also, making sure the spelling in your question is correct will help attracting good answers.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it readable, but I second Mariano's wish that the OP should define the notion of admissible.

Comment: It'd also be good for the OP to provide some motivation for how this question came up and why it's interesting.  As it stands it looks like possible homework to me.

Comment: Looks like OP is talking about this: http://blms.oxfordjournals.org/cgi/content/abstract/35/2/191 

Answer (score 11):

By theorems 5 and 6 of [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-5/issue-4/Complete-mappings-of-finite-groups/pjm/1103044383.full), the answer is yes when n is even and no when n is odd.